# What is this spade leafed plant?

Tags: identification, volunteer

We live in Denver and replaced some of our lawn with mulch a few years ago.  Earlier this summer a new friend appeared where we have not planted anything ourselves.  We used to have a maple tree about 20 feet away (cut down and the stump ground out) and 3 failed attempts at a pear tree about 12 to 15 feet away (but we don't recall the 8-9 foot trees ever having leaves this shape and certainly not as large as this!).

This plant has spade like leaves as seen in the pictures, and is current about a foot and a half to two feet tall after appearing a month or two ago.  We have been watering it every day, curious what it would turn into.

Thank you for your assistance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cottonwood or close relative ( popular). It will grow fast . Often considered undesirable.

Comment: The leaves don't quite look right; of course the plant is still young. Perhaps a different, member of the Populus genus?

Comment: One of our neighbors actually has a large cottonwood, and it's leaves look very much like these, so I believe that is most likely what it is.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be *Morus nigra* looking at the leaf close up, though quite why it would pop up on it's own I don't know - it wouldn't in the UK. https://www.ornamental-trees.co.uk/morus-nigra-p192